# Is it possible to update a text with an input's value in MS adaptive cards?

Tags: adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card with several inputs, and would like to show the user a synthesis of all the values that have been filled into the inputs before submitting.

Either a la:

- Real-time update of a textblock's text
- A button that gathers all input without submitting

I am on adaptive cards version 1.3

Have tried placing the inputs' ids as variable for the text block's value.
Thanks a lot!